# Javascript chooser

Tags: javascript, html

I had to make an html page where i can choose a random person from a list (which is my class).

I did this,but now i have mark and ignore the absent people from the random chooser.

Like an e-registry.

If you click on the button it SHOULD remove the name from the list and disable the button.

My problem is that i cant remove specific elements from the list.

It would be something like:

Not remove the number of string, rather than removing the actual string which says the same as the button.

Im sooo sorry for the hungarian comments but its mostly names and some quidance for me.

```html
<body>
   <h1 align="center"> Random választó MÉG SZAR </h1>
   <div align="center">
      <div>
         <button type="randomEmber" onclick="randomEmber()">Random Ember Kiválasztása</button>
         <input name="randomEmber" id="randomEmber" placeholder="Ne írj ide,el fog tűnni"> </input>
      </div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      Kik a hiányzók? <!-- ezt csináld meg -->
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick="this.disabled = true;Képes();" value="Képes"> Képes </button>
      <button onClick="this.disabled = true;Korsós();" value="Korsós"> Korsós </button>
      <button onClick="this.disabled = true;Lálóczki();" value="Lálóczki"> Lálóczki </button>
      <button onClick="this.disabled = true;Laukó();" value="Laukó"> Laukó </button>
      <button onClick="this.disabled = true;Neményi();" value="Neményi"> Neményi </button> <!-- ribait törli -->
      <button onClick="this.disabled = true;Pálya();" value="Pálya"> Pálya </button>
      <button onClick="this.disabled = true;Panajoth();" value="Panajoth"> Panajoth </button>
      <button onClick="this.disabled = true;Prepszl();" value="Prepszl"> Prepszl </button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick="this.disabled = true;Ribai();" value="Ribai"> Ribai </button> <!-- sipkát törli -->
      <button onClick="this.disabled = true;Sipka();" value="Sipka"> Sipka </button> <!-- Sipost törli -->
      <button onClick="this.disabled = true;Sipos();" value="Sipos"> Sipos </button> <!-- Stírt törli -->
      <button onClick="this.disabled = true;Stír();" value="Stír"> Stír </button> <!-- Szombatit törli -->
      <button onClick="this.disabled = true;Szombati();" value="Szombati"> Szombati </button> <!-- Tóthot törli -->
      <button onClick="this.disabled = true;Tóth();" value="Tóth"> Tóth </button> <!-- Vasst törli -->
      <button onClick="this.disabled = true;Vass();" value="Vass"> Vass </button> <!-- Zsolnait törli -->
      <button onClick="this.disabled = true;Zsolnai();" value="Zsolnai"> Zsolnai </button> <!-- ez jo -->
   </div>
   <br />
   <p align="center">Névsor:</p>
   <br />
   <p id="demo" align="center"></p>
   <script>
      var ember = Array(
       "Képes",
       "Korsós",
       "Lálóczki",
       "Laukó",
       "Neményi",
       "Pálya",
       "Panajoth",
       "Prepszl",
       "Ribai",
       "Sipka",
       "Sipos",
       "Stír",
       "Szombati",
       "Tóth",
       "Vass",
       "Zsolnai"
      );
      
      function randomEmber() {
       var randomEmber = ember[Math.floor(Math.random() * ember.length)];
       document.getElementById('randomEmber').value = randomEmber;
      }
      
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ember;
      
      // nem elegans de jo ez
      
      function Képes() {
         ember.shift();
      hianyzo.push("Képes");
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ember;
      }
      
      function Korsós() {
         ember.splice(1,1);
      hianyzo.push("Korsós");
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ember;
      }
      
      function Lálóczki() {
         ember.splice(2,1);
      hianyzo.push("Lálóczki");
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ember;
      }
      
      function Laukó() {
         ember.splice(3,1);
      hianyzo.push("Laukó");
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ember;
      }
      
      function Neményi() {
         ember.splice(4,1);
      hianyzo.push("Neményi");
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ember;
      }
      
      function Pálya() {
         ember.splice(5,1);
      hianyzo.push("Pálya");
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ember;
      }
      
      function Panajoth() {
         ember.splice(6,1);
      hianyzo.push("Panajoth");
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ember;
      }
      
      function Prepszl() {
         ember.splice(7,1);
      hianyzo.push("Prepszl");
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ember;
      }
      
      function Ribai() {
         ember.splice(9,1);
      hianyzo.push("Ribai");
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ember;
      }
      
      function Sipka() {
         ember.splice(10,1);
      hianyzo.push("Sipka");
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ember;
      }
      
      function Sipos() {
         ember.splice(11,1);
      hianyzo.push("Sipos");
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ember;
      }
      
      function Stír() {
         ember.splice(12,1);
      hianyzo.push("Stír");
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ember;
      }
      
      function Szombati() {
         ember.splice(13,1);
      hianyzo.push("Szombati");
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ember;
      }
      
      function Tóth() {
         ember.splice(14,1);
      hianyzo.push("Tóth");
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ember;
      }
      
      function Vass() {
         ember.splice(15,1);
      hianyzo.push("Vass");
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ember;
      }
      
      function Zsolnai() {
         ember.pop();
      hianyzo.push("Zsolnai");
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ember;
      }
      // nem elegans de jo ez
      
      // csinalj minden embernek egay myfunvtion2...t-ot ember.slice(0,x)  el
      
      if (randomEmber == null){
        alert("Nincs senki ma az órán????");
      }
      
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
      
      // TUDOTT HIBÁK:
      // ha nincs egy név se,akk undefiniedet ír ki az input
      
   </script>
   <br />
   <p align="center"> Hiányzók: </p>
   <script>
      var hianyzo = Array(
      );
      
      document.getElementById("hianyzo").innerHTML = hianyzo;
   </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code signals to me that you're quite new, so I won't be doing a massive overhaul of your code. You should know that you don't need to create an individual function to remove individual name from your array.

You only need one:

```
  function remove(name) {
   ember.splice( ember.indexOf(name), 1);
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ember;
  }
```

By using `indexOf` you can search the array for the correct index of the passed in name.

```
remove('Képes')
```

The above will search the array for Képes and remove that name. It will then recreate the array in the `demo` area.

In the comments you also stated you needed to add the removed user to `hianyo`. The following change will allow you to do that:

```
function remove(name) {
  ember.splice(ember.indexOf(name), 1); //remove from ember
  hianyzo.push(name); //add to hianyzo
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ember; // show updated ember
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = hianyzo; // show updated hianyzo
}
```

In the above any time we remove a name from ember, we add it to hianyzo, and then we display the changes for both arrays.

In addition to that change I also updated your random function:

```
function randomEmber() {
if(ember.length === 0) { alert("Nincs senki ma az órán????"); return; } 
//if the array is empty, alert the user and stop.
// otherwise...
var e = ember[Math.floor(Math.random() * ember.length)]; //get random user
document.getElementById("randomEmber").value = e; //show random user
}
```

The above simply checks if you've removed all your classmates. If you have it'll alert the user and stop the function from continuing. This will keep `undefined` from appearing in your `randomEmber` box.

```js
var ember = Array("Képes", "Korsós", "Lálóczki", "Laukó", "Neményi", "Pálya", "Panajoth", "Prepszl", "Ribai", "Sipka", "Sipos", "Stír", "Szombati", "Tóth", "Vass", "Zsolnai"), hianyzo = [];

function randomEmber() {
  if(ember.length === 0) { alert("Nincs senki ma az órán????"); return; } //if the array is empty, alert the user and stop.
  var e = ember[Math.floor(Math.random() * ember.length)]; //get random user
  document.getElementById("randomEmber").value = e; //show random user
}

function remove(name) {
  ember.splice(ember.indexOf(name), 1); //remove from ember
  hianyzo.push(name); //add to hianyzo
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ember; // show updated ember
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = hianyzo; // show updated hianyzo
}

document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = hianyzo; // show initial hianyzo
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ember; //show initial ember
```

```html
<h1 align="center"> Random választó MÉG SZAR </h1>
<div align="center">
  <div>
    <button type="randomEmber" onclick="randomEmber()">Random Ember Kiválasztása</button>
    <input name="randomEmber" id="randomEmber" placeholder="Ne írj ide,el fog tűnni"> </input>
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br /> Kik a hiányzók?
  <!-- ezt csináld meg -->
  <br />
  <br />
  <button onClick="this.disabled = true;remove('Képes');" value="Képes"> Képes </button>
  <button onClick="this.disabled = true;remove('Korsós');" value="Korsós"> Korsós </button>
  <button onClick="this.disabled = true;remove('Lálóczki');" value="Lálóczki"> Lálóczki </button>
  <button onClick="this.disabled = true;remove('Laukó');" value="Laukó"> Laukó </button>
  <button onClick="this.disabled = true;remove('Neményi');" value="Neményi"> Neményi </button>
  <!-- ribait törli -->
  <button onClick="this.disabled = true;remove('Pálya');" value="Pálya"> Pálya </button>
  <button onClick="this.disabled = true;remove('Panajoth');" value="Panajoth"> Panajoth </button>
  <button onClick="this.disabled = true;remove('Prepszl');" value="Prepszl"> Prepszl </button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <button onClick="this.disabled = true;remove('Ribai');" value="Ribai"> Ribai </button>
  <!-- sipkát törli -->
  <button onClick="this.disabled = true;remove('Sipka');" value="Sipka"> Sipka </button>
  <!-- Sipost törli -->
  <button onClick="this.disabled = true;remove('Sipos');" value="Sipos"> Sipos </button>
  <!-- Stírt törli -->
  <button onClick="this.disabled = true;remove('Stír');" value="Stír"> Stír </button>
  <!-- Szombatit törli -->
  <button onClick="this.disabled = true;remove('Szombati');" value="Szombati"> Szombati </button>
  <!-- Tóthot törli -->
  <button onClick="this.disabled = true;remove('Tóth');" value="Tóth"> Tóth </button>
  <!-- Vasst törli -->
  <button onClick="this.disabled = true;remove('Vass');" value="Vass"> Vass </button>
  <!-- Zsolnait törli -->
  <button onClick="this.disabled = true;remove('Zsolnai');" value="Zsolnai"> Zsolnai </button>
  <!-- ez jo -->
</div>
<br />
<p align="center">Névsor:</p>
<br />
<p id="demo" align="center"></p>
<br />
<p align="center"> Hiányzók: </p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
```

Comment: Yeah im pretty new to javascript. Thank you very much for your answer :)

Comment: You left out the remove word for the second block of buttons (i think sorry if im mistaken) so i edited like this "<button onClick="this.disabled = true;remove('Zsolnai');" value="Zsolnai"> Zsolnai </button>"

Comment: Can i handle the "undefined" text in the input box if i removed all the names from the list by the buttons?

Comment: @SiposPéter hi, I'll take a look in just a little while.

Comment: @SiposPéter I'm working on a solution. Can I ask, what is the difference between Hiányzók and Névsor ? Sorry, I don't know hungarian haha. Are all names supposed to start out in both lists, and when you click them they're removed from both?

Comment: Yeah im sorry. Hiányzók means the absent students, and Névsor means name list

Comment: All the names supposed to start in just the "Névsor" list and than if the user clicks on the name's button it shoud disappear from the "Névsor" and go and take place in "Hiányzók"

Comment: @SiposPéter Ohh! I see. Sure, no problem. Give me a few minutes and I'll give you an updated solution :)

Comment: Take your time. Im happy to have nice people who are helping :)

Comment: @SiposPéter Okay, go ahead and take a look. I added comments and updated my answer to more thoroughly explain.

Comment: Man you are amazing

Comment: @SiposPéter Happy to help!

Comment: what does hianyzo = []; this means? in the end of the ember array

Comment: @SiposPéter In JavaScript you have things called Constructors. For instance, `new Array()` is considered a constructor. But there are short-hands for those constructors. For example when you make a string variable you don't typically say `var str = new String("my string")` you just write `var str = "my string"` - in that same way instead of writing `var arr = new Array(1,2,3,4,5)` - you can simply write `var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]`. In the case of `hianyzo = []` It's simply the short-hand version of `hianyzo = new Array()`.  Make sense?

Comment: @SiposPéter Again, no problem! To accept an answer to your question by the way, be sure to check the green checkmark next to the answer :)